# Error downloading url file

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I get this error when I attempt to download a file from a link I get this error no matter what I try and look up and to do 
Im using

```
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

My code is

```
 elif message.content.startswith('``'):
    countn = (count+1)
    print(countn)
    print('ADD')
    meme = (message.content)
    memen = meme.replace("``", "")
    print(memen)
    print('Converted')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(memen, meme)
    await client.send_message (message.channel, "Added!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403: FORBIDDEN means that the server is denying you access to the resources, either because you have failed to supply sufficient authentication or because it blocks the default python user agent (`Python.urllib/3.X`).

[urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) is actually a legacy interface as it was ported from Python 2. You should consider using `urlopen` instead.

Anyway, one solution to this is to add a (spoofed) user-agent to your request, which can't be done using urlretrieve...

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(resp.read())
```

This wont fix issues for sites that require a login, but it will fix a lot of sites that don't.